# Page Not Found bug or SO showing wrong URL in story preferences screen

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, developer-story, 404-not-found

I got **page not found** error when I go to these below links.
https://stackoverflow.com/story/

https://stackoverflow.com/cv/

I already cleared the catch and also I have opened and checked this in a private window and am using the Internet Explorer browser.

[image]

### Edit:

Actually I got those URLs in the story preferences screen:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/storypreferences/2218635#slug

You can check this from the below image.

[image]

### Suggestion

> As per the @Eric comment those (https://stackoverflow.com/story/) links should be like this: https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/2218635 ???

Comment: What exactly did you expect to find? The link to your developer story is https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/2218635/. I'm not that familiar with the cv url.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't entered a slug.

You need to enter a name in the custom name field, then those links in the bottom will have that name added to it, and will work.

[image: Glorious freehand circles and freehand text]

Comment: But I have already did it..  Still the links are showing

Comment: Well, you haven't in your screenshot. Please share one where you've actually entered something then. Note that the slug needs to be unique.